# getting the value of parameters in php script using prototype

Tags: php, prototypejs

I need to send to an ajax function two parameters. How can I get the values in my Php file? I simply write $comment=$_GET["comment"]; but this did not send the written value.

my prototype script is as follows:

```
comment= $F('comment');  //text from textarea
name= $F('name');  // text from text box
var ajaxUrl = 'addcomment.php';

new Ajax.Request(ajaxUrl,
    {
     method:'post', 
     parameters: {comment: comment, name: name},        
     onSuccess: function(data){

        alert(data.responseText);

     }

});
```

php:

```
$comment=$_GET["comment"];
```

Answer (score 1):

at php file try this

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
echo 'Echoing name : '.$name.'\n'.'Echoing comment : '.$comment.'\n';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$name    = $_POST['name'];

echo $name.':'.$comment;
```

You can also inspect all the data that's getting sent using:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

You can take it further, by setting defaults for comment & name if not present:

```
$comment = (isset($_POST['comment']))? $_POST['comment'] : 'Default Comment';
$name    = (isset($_POST['name']))? $_POST['name'] : 'Default Name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change PHP code to

```
$comment=$_POST["comment"];
```